# virt-manager on Mac OS X can't connect to remote libvirtd

Tags: macos, homebrew, libvirt

I have installed virt-manager 1.3.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.5 via homebrew.
When I try to connect to my remote libvirtd daemon, running on a different machine at 192.168.1.70, I cannot connect.
However, when I try to connect to that same libvirtd from a VMware VM running Ubuntu on that same Mac, everything works fine.
Here's the error message I get from virt-manager on Mac OS:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.

An error occurred, but the cause is unknown

Verify that the 'libvirtd' daemon is running
on the remote host.

Libvirt URI is: qemu+ssh://root@192.168.1.70:1705/system?socket=/var/run/libvirt/system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/virt-manager/1.3.2/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 903, in _do_open
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/virt-manager/1.3.2/libexec/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 148, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/virt-manager/1.3.2/libexec/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: An error occurred, but the cause is unknown
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I eventually found a workaround posted on github by Billygoat32:

> Interesting... trying to add the host through the UI I get the above
> error. Using this command adds it and works for future connection:

```
virt-manager -c 'qemu+ssh://user@libvirthost/system?socket=/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock'
```